# How to read in only the first value from a text file

Tags: c++, file

Here is the logic:

```
read first integer from the text file into IntegerOne

if end-of-file on intInput.dat
display error message “Input file exists but has no values”
end program execution
```

The text file may not have any values, or it may have multiple values. If there is no value, then I want it to display the error message, if it has multiple values, then I only want to read in the first value and store the value into IntegerOne.

I understand if I want to read in an array of values, then I can do something like this:

```
int main() {

    int arr[30];
    ifstream is("InputFile.txt");
    int cnt = 0;
    int x;
    while (cnt < arr[30] && is >> x)
    {
        arr[cnt++] = x;
    }
    cout << "The integers are:" << "\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
        cout << arr[i] << ' ';
    }
    is.close();
}
```

But I am not exactly sure how to read in only the first value, should I just change “arr[30]” to “arr[1]”? I am hesitating to do that because, later, I will need to read in the second value only (and check if it exists). Any comments would be appreciated!

Comment: `arr[30]` in the first loop is out of bounds anyway, because you declared `int arr[30];`, so it has 30 elements, from index 0 to 29. And `arr[30]` will read garbage data, possibly the first 4 bytes of the `is` object

Comment: Where do you want to store the first value?  In a variable?  In an array?  In a `std::vector`?  `std::list`?

Comment: @Thomas Matthews In a variable

Comment: `is >> x` reads a value from the file into a variable. Just do this once, rather than in a loop.

Comment: Note: if the first token in the file cannot be converted to an integer `>>` will require a bit more help.

Comment: It is unclear if you intend `IntegerOne` to be a first-value that is separate from the remaining values that, if present, are read into an array, or whether you intend `arr[0] = IntegerOne;`? (a common beginning format is to include the 1st value in the file being the count of values to be read below it) Can you please clarify?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are trying to do several things with your code that can be easily done in sequence. As asked in the comment, it is unclear whether your `IntegerOne` you want to read is a value that is separate from the remaining values you want to read into your array or whether it is the first array element. (having a single separate integer on the first line containing a number that specifies the number of values that follow is a common format -- which we will presume is what you mean)

First off, avoid using *Magic-Numbers* or *Hardcoded Filenames* in your code. If you need a constant to declare your array, then either `#define` a constant, or declare a `const int` value. For the filename to open, `main()` takes arguments, `int main (int argc, char **argv)`(where argc is the *argument-count* telling you how many individual character strings are held in your *argument-vector*) that let you pass the filename to open as the first argument to your program (or you can take it as input on `stdin`). That way you have one convenient place to change your array size and you don't need to recompile your program just to read from another file.

For example, defining a constant for your array `arr` can be done as either:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

#define MAXI 30 /* if you need a constant, #define one, or declare const int */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {
    ...
    int arr[MAXI] = {0};        /* array of MAXI (30) integers */
```

or instead of using `#define`, in C++ you can declare and initialize a `const int`, e.g.

```
const int MAXI = 30;
```

With that background out of the way, how do you read the first integer value from the file into a variable named `IntegerOne`? (I think you were intending to use `x` in your code). Regardless what name you use, the approach is the same. Declare a variable to hold the integer value, open your file (validate it is open for reading) and then read the first value into your variable (validating that the read succeeds), e.g.

```
    int IntegerOne;             /* separate variable for IntegerOne */
    ...
    std::ifstream f (argv[1]);  /* open file stream */

    if (!f.good()) { /* validate file stream state good */
        std::cerr << "error: file open failed.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(f >> IntegerOne)) {    /* read/validate 1st value */
        std::cerr << "Input file exists but has no values.\n";
        return 1;
    }
```

If you have reached this point in your program, your have successfully read the first value from the file into `IntegerOne` and you can simply output the value to confirm:

```
    std::cout << "IntegerOne: " << IntegerOne << '\n';  /* output IntegerOne */
```

The next task is to read values up to the size of your array. You declare your array using the integer constant `MAXI` (max no. of integers) defined above:

```
    int arr[MAXI] = {0};        /* array of MAXI (30) integers */
```

(**note:** it is useful to initialize your POA's (plain old arrays) to all zero to prevent the inadvertent read from an element that has not yet had a value set during a loop which would invoke *Undefined Behavior*)

To protect your array bounds while validating each read into an element of your array, you can simply use the constant you defined along with a counter to prevent writing more integers than you have space for to your array. You validate each read just as you did with `IntegerOne` above. Putting both conditions together, you could do:

```
    int cnt = 0,                /* counter for array values */
    ...
    /* read remaining integers into arr up to MAXI values */
    while (cnt < MAXI && f >> arr[cnt])
        cnt++;
```

Now you have read your first value into `IntegerOne` and all remaining values in the file to your array. You can output them or use them any way you like from this point forward. The example below just output the values read or the error messages you specified (plus the additional message if the filename provided does not exist).

Putting it altogether you could do:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>

#define MAXI 30 /* if you need a constant, #define one, or declare const int */

int main (int argc, char **argv) {

    if (argc < 2) { /* validate at least 1 argument for filename */
        std::cerr << "usage: " << argv[0] << " filename\n";
        return 1;
    }

    int IntegerOne,             /* separate variable for IntegerOne */
        cnt = 0,                /* counter for array values */
        arr[MAXI] = {0};        /* array of MAXI (30) integers */
    std::ifstream f (argv[1]);  /* open file stream */

    if (!f.good()) { /* validate file stream state good */
        std::cerr << "error: file open failed.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    if (!(f >> IntegerOne)) {    /* read/validate 1st value */
        std::cerr << "Input file exists but has no values.\n";
        return 1;
    }
    std::cout << "IntegerOne: " << IntegerOne << '\n';  /* output IntegerOne */

    /* read remaining integers into arr up to MAXI values */
    while (cnt < MAXI && f >> arr[cnt])
        cnt++;

    /* output array, 10 values per line */
    for (int i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {
        if (i && i % 10 == 0)
            std::cout << '\n';
        std::cout << std::setw(5) << arr[i];
    }
    if (cnt)  /* conditionally output final newline if array values printed */
        std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Whenever you write code that has to satisfy several conditions, go test those conditions to validate your code works as intended.

**Example Use/Output**

Non-existent file:

```
$ ./bin/read1stvalue+array goldfish
error: file open failed.
```

Empty file:

```
$ ./bin/read1stvalue+array dat/empty.txt
Input file exists but has no values.
```

File with single-integer value `321`:

```
$ ./bin/read1stvalue+array dat/oneint.txt
IntegerOne: 321
```

File with 10 integer values after 1st value in file, e.g.

```
$ cat dat/int_cnt+10_by-5.txt
10
  702  344  138   77  294
   27   67  978  727  301
```

Reading above file, outputting array values 10 per-line:

```
$ ./bin/read1stvalue+array dat/int_cnt+10_by-5.txt
IntegerOne: 10
  702  344  138   77  294   27   67  978  727  301
```

File with 30 integer values after 1st value in file, e.g.

```
$ cat dat/int_cnt+30_by-5.txt
30
  393  936   97  365  928
  257  645  987  221   22
  237  853  584  905  819
  910  576  730  859  495
   13  818  281  908  582
  421  156  177  831  646
```

Reading above file, outputting array values 10 per-line:

```
$ ./bin/read1stvalue+array dat/int_cnt+30_by-5.txt
IntegerOne: 30
  393  936   97  365  928  257  645  987  221   22
  237  853  584  905  819  910  576  730  859  495
   13  818  281  908  582  421  156  177  831  646
```

File with 50 integer values after 1st value in file, e.g.

```
$ cat dat/int_cnt+50_by-5.txt
50
  302  697  190  743  391
  709  699  824  839  976
  817  246  695  833  918
    2  712  422  737  326
  706  170  394  720  903
  798  291  683  682  971
   70  216  668  260  960
   59  969  891  883   40
  867  700  519  795  766
  437   29  710   91  767
```

Reading above file, outputting array values 10 per-line:

```
$ ./bin/read1stvalue+array dat/int_cnt+50_by-5.txt
IntegerOne: 50
  302  697  190  743  391  709  699  824  839  976
  817  246  695  833  918    2  712  422  737  326
  706  170  394  720  903  798  291  683  682  971
```

(**note** only first 30 values are stored in array)

---

**Use STL Containers Instead of Plain Old Arrays**

While there is nothing wrong with knowing how to handle plain old arrays -- there is decades worth of legacy C++ using them, new code should make use of the containers provided by the standard template library which provide for automatic memory management, the ability to add additional elements if needed, etc.. `std::vector` can be used to replace any plain old array. Take a minute to look though how it is used and the examples provided for each of the member functions at [std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector). (they really do make life much easier)

Let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: While `int a[N]={0}` zero-out the array, `{1}` does not one-out the array - it only sets the first element to one. I would use `{}`.

Comment: `a[N]={0}` zeros all elements of the array, `a[N]={1}` sets first element to `1` and the rest to `0` by default.

Comment: We are saying the same thing. What I am trying to say is someone could imply, from `a[N]={0}`, that `a[N]={X}` sets all elements to `X`, so `a[N]={}` is a better option.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. Yes, a[N]={}, is probably the better choice on C++. In either case, the programmer will either need to know that *aggregate initialization* is available from C++11 on, or that `{0}` is the universal initializer and a hold-over from C.

Answer (score 3):

- Specify the **full path** when opening the stream:

  ```
  ifstream is( "c:/temp/test.txt" );  // the file is automatically closed on destruction
  ```
- You must check the **file was successfully opened**:

  ```
  if ( !is ) // did we succesfully open the file
  {
    cout << "could not open file";
    return -1;
  }
  ```
- You can **read the integer and check the success** in one step:

  ```
  if ( is >> value )
    cout << "contains one value, at least";
  else
    cout << "empty file";
  ```

Comment: Using absolute or relative paths has nothing to do with the question, but the rest is good advice. Especially the last part,  use the status of the stream to detect errors.

Comment: @drRobertz It is just a good habit: the location of the executable and the input file might be different - no room for doubt.

Answer (score 2):

This is one method to read in the first value:

```
int first_value;
is >> first_value;
```

If you need to, you can store it in the array:
`arr[0] = first_value;`

To read directly into the first value of the array:
`is >> arr[0];`

Answer (score 2):

Well, your code must be simpler than that because you only want to read the first value. You should use the following code as an example for what is required:

```
ifstream is("InputFile.txt"); //open file
if(!is){
   //file can't be opened for some reason (e.g. doesn't exist)
   return;
}
int first_value = -1;
if(is.peek() != EOF){
   //file isn't empty empty
   is >> first_value;
}
is.close();
```

Comment: It won't work for a file made of white-spaces. Also, you must return an integer.

Comment: I don't say that my code will work typically with the OP's scenario. However, I mentioned that it's just an example for what can be done to get around the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Answer for use C++17 ore Boost

1. use std :: filesystem to manage the paths
2. check the file exists and file size > 0 (std::filesystem::exists(path) and std::filesystem::file_size(path))
3. if everything is ok - read the file (use fstream)

see code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <filesystem>
#include <fstream>


int main() {

    auto path{std::filesystem::current_path() / "data"};

    if (!std::filesystem::exists(path)) {
       return -1;
    } else {
        std::cout << "File exists!" << std::endl;
    }

    uint64_t file_size{std::filesystem::file_size(path)};
    if (!file_size) {
        return -2;
    } else {
        std::cout << "File size : " << file_size << std::endl;
    }

    std::fstream in_stream{path, std::ios::in};

    char ch;
    in_stream.read(&ch, 1);

    std::cout << "first byte is : " << ch << std::endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Answering a question for a new C++ programmer, it never hurts to explain the [Filesystem library](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/filesystem) was not part of C++ until C++17 -- just in case the compiler they are attempting to use isn't quite up to date. Otherwise they will need to look to the Boost library for the functionality.